# Can I sandbox test in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my iPhone application we have in-app items.

My In app item's status is Ready to Submit. Can I do sandbox testing while having this status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This status just means that you can upload the binary to iTunes Connect. You can still test and debug your purchasable items while this is the status.

Comment: Same issue facing with Sanbox Enviroment. My product on iTunes has "Ready to Submit" status Do I need to upload app on app store ? or I can test In-App-Purchase funda without submitting app on App store with Sanbox Enviroment?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I just went through this process, took many trial and errors, when all I need to do was follow apples instructions. Make test users. and MOST important, do not upload screen shot when setting up in app purchase product..save... then status should say, waiting for screenshot. And you can test right away. No need to wait hours or even minutes in my case. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1329.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do sandbox testing by creating test user.

Steps to create testuser -

1. Go to iTunes Connect
2. Manage Users
3. select test user

It will ask for email id. Enter email id which is not yet used for apple tr

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this without any issues just follow apple in app purchase guidelines

[In app purchase guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)